# Checking the arity of a method object

Tags: scala

Given any method, eg

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int) = {
    x + y
}
```

Can I use any inspection/reflection library to obtain the arity of `add`?

Something like `arity(add)`, since the function object does not seems to have a property to provide that information.

Comment: In order to do what?

Comment: I want a `Node` object to spawn as many branches as the arity of the function `f` it receives in the constructor, eg `add`

Comment: `add` is a method, not a function. Those are very different. Are you asking about methods or functions?

Comment: You're right. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One type-safe solution is to overload your `Node`'s constructor for each `Function*` trait that corresponds to the arity of a function that you will pass as a parameter:

```scala
scala> class Node {
     |   def this(f: Function0[Int]) = { this(); println(0) }
     |   def this(f: Function1[Int, Int]) = { this(); println(1) }
     |   def this(f: Function2[Int, Int, Int]) = { this(); println(2) }
     | }
defined class Node

scala> new Node(add _)
2
res7: Node = Node@427128a6
```

If your situation requires a reflection-based approach somehow, you can count the number of parameters of the `apply` method that all the `Function*` traits share, as follows:

```
scala> def arity(f: AnyRef): Option[Int] = {
     |   val apply = f.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "apply")
     |   apply.map(_.getParameterCount)
     | }
arity: (f: AnyRef)Option[Int]

scala> arity(add _)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Or you might want to consider using typed patterns:

```
def arity(f: AnyRef): Int = f match {
  case _: Function0[_] => 0
  case _: Function1[_, _] => 1
  case _: Function2[_, _, _] => 2
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer @dkim. The typed patterns approach looks clean if you want to avoid the reflection approach.